# How to change character value for schema in functions?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce. And I need through the **functions.php** file, change the value of the symbol `"priceCurrency": "UAH"`, to `"priceCurrency": "UAH2`".

I understand that this is not correct for the schema.
But I need to test!
Option through the admin panel is not suitable, since. I need so.

How to transfer the value to change the character?

### 2

I use Polylang to transform my pages, and so it would be necessary that the store be in different languages ​​with different currencies of the corresponding page.
For this, I used such code to change the translation for different pages.

```
function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
$currencies['UAH '] = __( 'Українська гривня', 'woocommerce' );
return $currencies;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency) {
    $my_lang = pll_current_language(); // polylang
if ( $my_lang == 'en' ) {
     $grn =' EUR ';
     } else {
         $grn ='  грн  ';
         } 

switch( $currency ) {
case 'UAH': $currency_symbol = $grn; break;
break;
}
return $currency_symbol;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'mycustom_variation_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'mycustom_variation_price', 10, 2 );
```

It worked great and in different languages ​​I saw different currencies. But when I looked at the source code for the schema markup. I saw that **UAH** did not change to **EUR**.

```
[{"@type":"Offer","price":"7046","priceSpecification":{"price":"7046","priceCurrency":"UAH","valueAddedTaxIncluded":"false"},"priceCurrency":"UAH"
```

Comment: Please explain the context where you want to change the currency symbol - more details on the question will be helpful

Comment: @MujeebuRahman Thanks for the tip, I supplemented the question.

Comment: Upvoted the question